# No method 'sparkline'

Tags: jquery, sparklines

I've got the following code (based on [this page](http://www.omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/)):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.sparkline.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
    alert($('.test').html());
    $('.test').sparkline();
});
</script>
```

EDIT: Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<span class="test">1,2,3</span>
```

I get the alert, which shows `1,2,3`, but the error console (in Chrome) says `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'sparkline'`. Have I overlooked something?

Comment: A stupid question but did you put `jquery.sparkline.js` in the `js` folder?

Comment: No problem there: no 404 error, and when I view the page source I can click the sparkline filename and bring up the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check 2 things

1. That `jquery.sparkline.js` is actually present in your `/js/` folder.
2. That you're not including jQuery again further down the page, which would effectively remove any plugins you included before it (since it redefines `$`/`jQuery`).